# Check if queue exists in Solace

Tags: solace

I'm using Java API to connect to Solace, provision queues and subscribe them to topics. In case those queues are already exists I would like to avoid doing it again. Using Java API is it possible to check if particular queue exists and which topics are mapped to that queue?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to attempt to provision, and make use of the `JCSMPSession.FLAG_IGNORE_ALREADY_EXISTS` and `JCSMPProperties.IGNORE_DUPLICATE_SUBSCRIPTION_ERROR` properties.

Here's an quick example:

```
JCSMPProperties properties = new JCSMPProperties();
properties.setProperty(JCSMPProperties.HOST, "your_router_dns_name");
properties.setProperty(JCSMPProperties.USERNAME, "default");
properties.setBooleanProperty(JCSMPProperties.IGNORE_DUPLICATE_SUBSCRIPTION_ERROR, true);

JCSMPSession session =  JCSMPFactory.onlyInstance().createSession(properties);

Queue queue = JCSMPFactory.onlyInstance().createQueue("myqueue");
EndpointProperties props = new EndpointProperties(); // default properties, modify as needed
session.provision(queue, props, JCSMPSession.FLAG_IGNORE_ALREADY_EXISTS);

Topic topic = JCSMPFactory.onlyInstance().createTopic("my/topic");
session.addSubscription(queue, topic, JCSMPSession.WAIT_FOR_CONFIRM);
```

Note that there's no actual method to verify if the queue and topic subscriptions exist using the API. If absolutely necessary, you can make use of [SEMP over message bus](https://docs.solace.com/SEMP/Using-Legacy-SEMP.htm#SEMP3) to execute `show` commands, but this is pretty unwieldy.